# Sum of all child and assign to parent in hierarchical data in MySql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, hierarchical-data

I have a 2 Mysql tables like 1.Product(This table is hierarchical or recursive) and 2.Sales table in this will store sale id and product id. I need to show parent product with the sum of all hierarchical child product.

Product table having data like,

```
    id    name         parent_id
1     Necklace       NULL
2     Ring           NULL
3     Earing         NULL
4     Choker         1
5     Long Necklace  1
6     Short Necklace 1
7     2-Line         5
8     3-Line         5
9     Mango          5
10    Green          7
11    Red            7
12    White          7
13    Stud           3
```

Sales table will have data like,

```
id    product_id     no_of_pcs          weight      rate
1       10              5                 40        35000
2       12              8                 50        50000
3       9               2                 20        25000
4       6               1                  8        25000
5       13              2                 16        22000
```

Now I'm trying the result as,

```
Product         sale_pcs    tot_pcs        sale_wt      sale_rate
1               Necklace      16                 118          135000 
3               Earing         2                  16           22000
```

Now I'm using mysql query inside php recursive function by using product table. By using this even recursive function all the products need to check with sales table. This will happening performance issue. Could you please help any one to solve this issue whether this possible by doing in query itself

Comment: You are more likely to get a response if you write all details into your question in _text,_ not as screenshots. This is one of the recommendations in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @BillKarwin I have updated my question and created in table structure now.